# How to replace single and double digit numbers with single character in js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, regular-language, regexp-replace

I have an essay as a big string with letters and numbers (as page numbers) (only single digit and double digits). I want all of them to be replaced by "#". I tried str.replace(/[0-9]/g,"#"), this worked for 0 to 9 numbers, but with the double digits, they were replaced by "##", so how can I replace them all with a single "#"?

Comment: How do you know if it is a double digit number or two single digit ones??

Comment: Use `[0-9]+`.....

Comment: Do you only want to replace one or two digits? What about 3 or more?

Comment: Can you do a second pass replacing ## with #?

Comment: yes the numbers are up to 99 and I want to replace all of them with a single "#"

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace only 1 or 2 digits in a line:

```js
str.replace(/[0-9]{1,2}/, "#")
```

If you want to replace all digits in a line:

```js
str.replace(/[0-9]+/g, "#")
```

Comment: This will replace strings of digits regardless of the length with "#". The OP is asking about how to replace only 1 or 2 digits.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Ok, I will add another variant.